# My Ubuntu 20.04 won't boot

Tags: boot, 20.04

I was uninstalling python which probably removed other packages from that directory. When I reboot, it won't show Ubuntu logo while booting and I'm stuck at black screen which says one line starting /dev/sda9 and some blocks. I can get into tty1,tty2 and tty3 though. I tried sudo update but it gives 403 forbidden IP error

Comment: Why did you try to uninstall Python? If you are trying to achieve something else, and decided to uninstall Python for that, you can ask a separate question about it.

Comment: My python was broken, I was unable to get some libraries run and it also said that my installation was partial. But now I just cant get anywhere